# Projects to improve keyboard input?

Tags: user-interface, autocomplete, keyboard, user-experience, diacritics

I've been bothered with this question for a while now: What projects are there out there for improving keyboard-based input? I've been searching and I can barely find anything. The only effort I can think of to really confront keyboard usability has been for touch screen keyboards on mobile devices, which are great. I'm typing on an iPhone right now since I didn't bring my computer on vacation, and my mother, who's always been the goofy old woman who types with one finger, got an Android phone with swipe-typing and loves it. I love how on my iPhone, I can even hold down a character to access diacritical marks and similar characters. It's great.

Meanwhile, the desktop space hasn't seen any significant improvements in forever. MacOS handles special characters more gracefully than Windows (which preposterously expects users to type ASCII code to type names like Zoë and Renée). I've tried using the US-International layout, which thankfully makes it easier to type è and ß and € among others, but it breaks too hard from the standard keyboard paradigm that I only use it when I have to type lots of special characters (US-international uses command sequences instead of modifier keys for accents, which changes the rhythm of typing).

I'm not really interested so much in learning alternate layouts. I've heard some encouraging anecdotes about Dvorak, but it doesn't solve the better part of my typing woes, and frankly it's too much effort to put into an *unproven* standard. But, there are *little* things that indeed are frustrating, like the location of the brackets and parentheses, which are incredibly frustrating to use for a poor typist like me trying to learn Python.

Anyway, the best thing I've seen to this end have been certain applications that add autocomplete and keyboard macros to the system, which is helpful, but a relatively small addition. Spellcheck has traditionally been pretty disgraceful, and I don't know of any effort to improve it.

So anyway, are there any good projects out there for improving keyboard input? I would even be intrigued by projects for entirely new keyboard designs if they aim to solve use, instead of just repetitive strain (which isn't a problem for me because I rarely type much). What is there?

Answer (score 0):

1. Bind a shortcut key to change the keyboard layout settings, i use the windows key and spacebar. You can use say german when you are typing in german, and switch back to english when you are done. This is very easy in Ubuntu, on Windows it might be possible with Autohotkey - http://www.autohotkey.com/
2. Text Expanders - these programs allow you to define a sequence such as !ef - and they will automatically insert text you have defined with that sequence. If i had my email footer attached with !ef it would have been inserted above. http://www.Lifehacker.com have some good articles on the subject
3. kbdedit - http://www.kbdedit.com/ - I've never needed this program but on the website it says:

   > Keyboard customization under Windows has never been easy.
   >   Fortunately, KbdEdit is here to turn it around: now it's never been easier! Twist your >keyboard into a pretzel sooner than you can say "heterosyllabic